# How to download full ubuntu on usb flash drive and allow it to dual boot off of windows pc

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd

Currently I have a linux live usb for Ubuntu but I do NOT want to replace windows on my pc and I also do NOT want to partion my built in drive in case some problem occurs. So I would like to know how to download full ubuntu OS onto flash drive or external HDD and allow it run ubuntu when its pluged in and windows when it is not.Sorry if obvious question but I have tried to find out how to install ubuntu on flash drive without using it to overwrite my current windows OS and have found nothing that I can understand. Any steps would be helpful please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the installer of the live version to install Ubuntu onto your external drive. You can boot to it in the same way you booted from the USB drive, by selecting the boot device before starting windows.

Comment: Is there a way to specify where to download once through the download menus?

Comment: When prompted whether to install alongside existing os or replacing them choose "Something else..." to set the partitions manually, there you can also choose between all internal and connected external hdds. Or boot from the USB stick after removing the internal drive, then it will probably install on the only connected one.

Answer (score 0):

Use your optical disc drive to create an Ubuntu install disc. Then insert the USB drive and boot from DVD.
Now install Ubuntu to USB drive.

To be absolutely sure windows won't get harmed, you can temporarily unplug the HDD if the hardware permits it. (Some laptops won't..)